# Find Bootstrap div with 100% width correct behavior

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, html-table

I'm trying to overflow a table in bootstrap with a loader div that has 100% width.

I've made a fiddle here:

https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/18316/

Here's the code:

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <div id="loaderTable"></div>
        <table class="table-bordered table-striped table-condensed" width="100%">
            <thead>
                <th>Data inizio</th>
                <th>Ora inizio</th>
                <th>Data fine</th>
                <th>Ora fine</th>
                <th>Attività</th>
                <th>Struttura</th>
                <th>Dettagli</th>
                <th>Salva evento</th>
                <th>Stato</th>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td data-title="Data inizio" id="prest_data_inizio">12/04/2016</td>
                    <td data-title="Ora inizio" id="prest_ora_inizio">09:00</td>
                    <td data-title="Data fine" id="prest_data_fine">12/04/2016</td>
                    <td data-title="Ora fine" id="prest_ora_fine">18:00</td>
                    <td data-title="Attività" id="prest_attivita">Attività di ambulatorio</td>
                    <td data-title="Struttura" id="prest_struttura">6</td>
                    <td data-title="Dettagli" id="prest_dettagli"><a href="javascript:void(0);"><i class="fa fa-chevron-circle-down"></i></a></td>
                    <td data-title="Salva evento" id="prest_salva"><a href="javascript:void(0);"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i></a></td>
                    <td data-title="Stato" id="prest_stato">9</td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="prest_dettagli_box">
                    <td data-title="Dettagli" colspan="9">
                        <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</span>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
            <tfoot>
            </tfoot>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#loaderTable {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 10;
    background: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.5) url(http://www.nasa.gov/multimedia/videogallery/ajax-loader.gif) no-repeat center center;
    top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

I don't understand the loader div width behavior (100% width) because if the div is nested inside a row and a `col-md-12` should not go outside but probably I didn't understand the grid philosophy in this case.

Can someone suggest me the right way to put this loader div above my table filling exactly the 100% of the width?

Comment: What your expected result? Loader on the whole page? The row? Can you create a picture whith your expected result?

Comment: Hi Mosh, thanks for the answer. The expected result is that the loader div should not exceed the left and right side of the table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happened because the parent with `relative` position is the `col-md-12` and he has `padding:0 15px` so, you just need to wrap the table with `div` and give it `position:relative`

```css
/* Latest compiled and minified CSS included as External Resource*/

/* Optional theme */
#loaderTable {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 10;
  background: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.5) url(http://www.nasa.gov/multimedia/videogallery/ajax-loader.gif) no-repeat center center;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.wrapper {
  position:relative;
}
```

```html
<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <div class="wrapper">

        <div id="loaderTable"></div>
        <table class="table-bordered table-striped table-condensed" width="100%">
          <thead>
            <th>Data inizio</th>
            <th>Ora inizio</th>
            <th>Data fine</th>
            <th>Ora fine</th>
            <th>Attività</th>
            <th>Struttura</th>
            <th>Dettagli</th>
            <th>Salva evento</th>
            <th>Stato</th>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td data-title="Data inizio" id="prest_data_inizio">12/04/2016</td>
              <td data-title="Ora inizio" id="prest_ora_inizio">09:00</td>
              <td data-title="Data fine" id="prest_data_fine">12/04/2016</td>
              <td data-title="Ora fine" id="prest_ora_fine">18:00</td>
              <td data-title="Attività" id="prest_attivita">Attività di ambulatorio</td>
              <td data-title="Struttura" id="prest_struttura">6</td>
              <td data-title="Dettagli" id="prest_dettagli"><a href="javascript:void(0);"><i class="fa fa-chevron-circle-down"></i></a></td>
              <td data-title="Salva evento" id="prest_salva"><a href="javascript:void(0);"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i></a></td>
              <td data-title="Stato" id="prest_stato">9</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="prest_dettagli_box">
              <td data-title="Dettagli" colspan="9">
                <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</span>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
          <tfoot>
          </tfoot>
        </table>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Ok, now I understand the rule! Thanks Mosh!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure, than understand this problem. You want to have loader cover only table not space in div "col-md-12".

If this is your problem, You must add another style "width", and "top" to loader style, because div "col-md-12" have "padding-right: 15px; padding-left: 15px;"

```css
#loaderTable {
    width: calc(100% - 30px); 
    left: 15px;  
}
```

Comment: Hi Karolina, your style is absolutely correct to solve the problem. My question is why, if the div is nested inside a container -> row -> col-12 the width set at 100% exceed the grid??!?

Comment: hmmm ".row"  heve "margin-right: -15px; margin-left: -15px;" that's why exceed the grid